# Symfony 2.4 Base Project Setup

Tags: php, symfony

I spent several years utilizing Symfony 1 for web projects and had a set list of settings, packages and custom files prepared so that when I wanted to start a new project, I had a solid base with good security, account management, backend, etc. already setup after only about 10 minutes. I've been out of it for a few years and would now like to do the same with Symfony 2.4. I've look around for any guides to setting up a good base project but have not found any specific for 2.4 nor the necessary settings that would need to be made in each for a solid, repeatable base.

For those out there who have been using Symfony 2 for a while, could you recommend the base bundles you essentially always include and any generalize settings you use? Are there guides/articles I have been unable to find specific to the updates in 2.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the bundles you can use to set up a good base project:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle - FOSUserBundle for easy user management

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle - Admin Generator

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle - If you need Restful APIs

https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle -Easily serialize, and deserialize data of any complexity

https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle‎ - Easy pagination

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle‎ - Expose routes to JS

https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle‎ - Expose translation to js

https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle

https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle‎ - Documentation generation for APIs

Also look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html for the installation guides.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh! There are a number of bundles there I had not known about and will be great additions.